# Can't find GIMP brush folder on Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, gimp

I'm using GIMP 2.10.22 on Debian. I believe it was installed using the official Debian Bullseye Stable repo.

All the tutorials and articles I've seen, up to now, say that GIMP 2.10 has its brushes located in /home//.gimp-X.X... However that folder isn't even present on my system.

Running Debian Bullseye Stable.

Answer (score 1):

In GIMP, all the asset directories, including the brushes directory, can be viewed and modified using `Edit > Preferences > Folders`. For the brushes folder specifically, select the `Brushes` entry under `Folders`.

This works on any operating system GIMP is available for, including Windows, MacOS, and most of Linux.

All this is explained in more detail in this [official GIMP tutorial](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Asset_Folders/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).